# Users Sync between Firebase Custom Auth and existing app and users database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, firebase-authentication

The company I work for has a production ROR web application that handles user authentication using devise on backend. I´ve been asked to develop a mobile app using specific IONIC 3 with firebase template, This app works along with existing ROR web app and I cannot modify backend auth, so I implemented Firebase´s Custom Token authentication and had it to work. For testing purposes I registered manually user accounts in Firebase console using existing username and uids on my baackend, but when I try to login using a user account that is not manually registered, I get the following exception "**there is no user record corresponding to this identifier**" I know it is because there is no user wit that uid in firebase, but reading the documentation I found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth)  it says "...After a user signs in for the first time, a new user account is created and linked to the credentials—that is, the user name and password, phone number, or auth provider information—the user signed in with. This new account is stored as part of your Firebase project, and can be used to identify a user across every app in your project, regardless of how the user signs in...." so my question is, Is there a way to have firebase register users automatically after using SigninWithCustomToken? Can anyone advise on a correct flow to achieve sync between current back end and firebase users?

I´ve never used firebase before and have not found more than very basic documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you signing in the user? What method is throwing the "there is no user record corresponding to this identifier" error? Custom authentication should never throw an error if the account doesn't exist. You must be using another method of sign in.

Comment: I´m using the following method which is the one throwing the error:
...
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithCustomToken(data.token)
...
where afAuth.
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
and auth inside angularfire is
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
:

Comment: `signInWithCustomToken` should not throw that error as it can create a new record if it doesn't exist. Can you inspect your network console. There should be a request to some endpoint `verifyCustomToken`. Can you copy the error response and post it?